# Service Stack Swagger 2.0 and Azure Api Management Import

Tags: import, servicestack, swagger, swagger-2.0, azure-api-management

I am trying to import my Service Stack swagger.json into an Azure Api Management instance. Its failing with "One or more fields contain incorrect values:
Parsing error(s): The Swagger version specified is unknown."

It seems that Azure API Management requires Swagger 2.0 but Service Stack only outputs Swagger 1.2.

Does anybody have a work around for this? Or know when Service Stack will start supporting Swagger 2.0?

Comment: Azure APIM should be able to handle Swagger 1.2. Do you have a sample file I could take a look at?

Comment: I got the same error when adding the API using the URL.  
When I copied the swagger JSON into the txt box it worked

Comment: I'm getting this error when using Swagger 2.0 as well. I'm assuming azure just doesn't support the latest versions of swagger, can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 2):

ServiceStack doesn't support Swagger 2.0, you can [vote for this feature request](https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests/suggestions/9940074-support-swagger-2-0) to get notified of updates.

Swagger spec has had multiple breaking changes over the years and the latest effort seems to now be rolled into https://www.openapis.org - we're waiting until this effort matures to see if it replaces Swagger 2.0 before commencing any rewrites that support it.

Comment: V3 has breaking changes but V2 to V3 migration should be fairly mechanical.  I'm working on a V3 parser here https://github.com/tavis-software/Tavis.OpenApi that hopefully will be able to parse V2 also and present it as a single DOM.

Comment: @mythz any update on this? Maybe Ii can help if you can guide me in right direction.

Comment: @Mayank no updates other than we've just assigned someone to work on it, but still too early to know when/how long it will take.

Comment: @mythz any plan on Swagger 2 support? Thx

Comment: @IvanFioravanti next v4.5.8 release will include OpenApi support, it's now in v4.5.7 on MyGet if you want to test it out early